# How to search values in Dictionary and replace it to an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mapping, nsdictionary

I have an array:

```
var placeID = ["55667","44568"]
```

And dictionary:

```
var placeDict = ["USA" : "55667",
             "Canada" : "44568"
            ]
```

I want to replace placeID objects with country names from placeDict.

So question is: if value of placeID matched with value in placeDict I want it need to be replaced to country name.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: What is your issue? What are you struggling with when trying to do it? Please explain.

Comment: Have no idea how to replace matched values in an array. If numbers matched i want to replace it with country name

Comment: If you have *no idea*, then I suggest you read the very well written [Swift language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) where you will find all explanations about sequences, collections and how to manipulate and *filter* them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is something very basic you would like to do. Just `map` on the dictionary containing the places and ids, and return the name of the country, when it is matching. `foundPlaceIDS` should contain the result you needed.

```
var placeIDs = ["55667","44568"]
var placeDict = ["USA" : "55667",
                 "Canada" : "44568"]

var foundPlaceIDs = placeDict.flatMap { (placeName, placeID) -> String? in
    return placeID.contains(placeID) ? placeName : nil
}

print(foundPlaceIDs) // Prints USA, Canada
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my code below, this is easy for you to understand:

```
var placeID = ["55667","44568"]
var placeDict = ["USA" : "55667",
                 "Canada" : "44568"]

for (key, value) in placeDict {
    for i in 0 ..< placeID.count {
        if placeID[i] == value {
            placeID[i] = key
        }
    }
}

print(placeID)  // -> ["USA", "Canada"]
```